# Associate colors to values in R

Tags: r, colors, numeric, associate

I needed help knowing how to associate colors with values.
For example, I have a vector for colors and values as follows i.e.

```
cols <- c("red", "gray60")
and 
numEra <- c(values)
numEra
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

How do I associate these values with the colors "red" and "gray60" ??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use `cut` like this:

```r
cols <- c("red", "gray60")
numEra <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)

cols[cut(numEra, 2)]
#> [1] "red"    "red"    "red"    "gray60" "gray60" "gray60"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So each number is now associated with a color.